# .sort() Не сортирует

Tags: java, arraylist, динамические-массивы

Размер ArrayList задаю через BufferedReader, вывожу сообщение о последнем элементе массива, далее сортирую .sort()-ом. Вывожу новое сообщение о последнем элементе. Результат тот-же. Всё что нужно импортировал.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int max = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    List<Integer> myIntArr = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i ++){
        myIntArr.add(Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()));
    }
    //reader.close();
    System.out.println("before sorting " + myIntArr.get(myIntArr.size()-1));

    Arrays.sort(new List[]{myIntArr});

    System.out.print("after sorting " + myIntArr.get(myIntArr.size()-1));
```

Почему-же не работает .sort()

Comment: Я случайно попал в этот вопрос, ничего не понимаю в java, извините, если чушь скажу, но разве `Arrays.sort(new List[]{myIntArr});` - это не создание нового списка из `myIntArr` и сортировка этого нового списка? А выводите Вы другой список, сам исходный `myIntArr`

Comment: Я в  java судя по всему смыслю ещё меньше вас, наверно так и есть. Но это не моя идея. Это мне подсказала Idea, без этой строки ругалась и подчёркивала красным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Collections.sort(myIntArr)
```

или

```
myIntArr.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder())
```

Comment: Спасибо Сергей, оба метода работают!